# which widget is used to sort column-wise data in tkinter GUI Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, sorting, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

I have written a GUI application in Python 2.7 in which many data are there to show in a column-wise. I just wanna to know that which widget should i use for shorting data column-wise so that the sorting widget will look good :-D or Which widget is used to sort column-wise data in tkinter GUI Python 2.7 ?

Comment: To my knowledge tkinter doesn't have any widget specifically designed for sorting, there are ways you could implement a sort function however we'd need to see an example of your code in order to advise on this.

Comment: You can use `ttk.Treeview`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ethan Field for your reply. Actually, i am not asking for any code or how to write any code for sorting. For viewing purpose which widget will look good, this is my question. i can use Button. when i will click button it will sort my data. but, i think some other widget will be there which will look better as compared to Button or any other .

Comment: I mean, Button is typically what you would use, however you can turn any widget into a Button by binding an on click event to it. So you could use a Label widget for example

Comment: Yes, compared to Button, Label will look Good.!! but, the problem is that Label doesn't support Command Options. When i click Label it should call a predefined Functions.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below script demonstrates that you can get a callback from a `Label` widget if you wanted to use that instead.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

label = Label(root, text="Click me")

label.pack()

def callback(event):
    print("You did it!")

label.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

root.mainloop()
```

The same logic can be applied to any widget, if you wanted to use a `Listbox` as a "button" (for some ungodly reason) for example, that's also possible with the same logic.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ethan Field. This is what I really want... and I also  learn a new concept from your above code.. thank you so much, dear.